# Ubuntu Sublime Text 2 Java Script compiling but not running

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm setting up Sublime text 2 and running:

```
console.log("Hello!");
```

But all I'm getting in the console is "finished in [0.0]

My build system is:

```
{
"cmd": ["node", "$file"],
"selector": "source.js"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This again is being done in Ubuntu.

Comment: what happens if you switch to your file's directory and run `node myfile.js` (or whatever it's called) from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

The [`nodejs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nodejs) package for Ubuntu provides `/usr/bin/nodejs`, not `/usr/bin/node`. The [`node`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/node) package, for amateur packet radio nodes, provides `/usr/sbin/node`, which is what your build system is running. It has nothing to do with Javascript, hence no output. There are two options (assuming you've already installed `nodejs`), and you can do one or both:

1. From the command line, run

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
   ```

   This will create a symlink to node that (I think, I'm not in Ubuntu at the moment) should be before `/usr/sbin` in your `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH` to verify the order of your path.
2. Change your build system to run `/usr/bin/nodejs` instead of `node`. This will fix your immediate problem, but if you don't run the other command above you may have issues with Sublime's `NodeJS` plugin.

Good luck!

Comment: Insteasd of getting
    [finished in 0.0] 
I am not getting
    [finishes in 0.1s]

That leads me to believe that the symlink is working and thus causing a slight delay, but no output yet.

Comment: @JjWoods did you change the `cmd` section of your build system?

Comment: I have not, just the node section. Should CMD be $PATH?

Comment: @JjWoods it should be `"cmd": ["/usr/bin/nodejs", "$file"],`

Comment: Yep, that's what it is. Still not showing any output just the finished line.

Comment: @JjWoods what happens if you run the file from the command line?

Comment: I managed to get it! I can't believe I did that but I just hadn't saved the file right this time haha. hi.jss was NOT right.